# Simplify doesn't simplify HypergeometricPFQ with exact arguments

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Consider a series:
$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{8^{-11-2t}(22+4t)!}{t!(11+t)!(11+2t)!(32+t)}$$

```
Sum[(8^(-11 - 2 t) (22 + 4 t)!)/(t! (11 + t)! (11 + 2 t)!) 1/(32 + t),{t,0,Infinity}]
```

I enter it into Mathematica, and get the following:
$$\frac{26880307030942914706481517908268600094665992\sqrt2}{2617883526123366341980485070559163273300330975\pi}\tag1$$

```
26880307030942914706481517908268600094665992 Sqrt[2]/(2617883526123366341980485070559163273300330975 Pi)
```

So far so good. Now I change $32$ to `q` and get the new answer:
$$\frac{88179{\;}_3 F_2\left(\frac{23}4,\frac{25}4,q;12,q+1;1\right)}{1073741824q}\tag2$$

```
88179 HypergeometricPFQ[{23/4, 25/4, q}, {12, 1 + q}, 1]/(1073741824 q)
```

OK, not bad. Let's now do `%/.q->32`. But... it remains in almost unchanged form of
$$\frac{88179{\;}_3 F_2\left(\frac{23}4,\frac{25}4,32;12,33;1\right)}{34359738368}\tag3$$
I now try doing `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, but it doesn't change. I tried checking $(1)$ and $(2)$ for equality with `==`, and still got unevaluated expression. Using `Reduce` over it gave me `True` with strange problem of

> Reduce::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity /* difference of LHS and RHS multiplied by denominator */ is equal to zero. Assuming it is. >>

Still, computing difference between ${}_3 F_2\left(\frac{23}4,\frac{25}4,32;12,33;1\right)$ and $\frac{923600316834709429658044469155615723122343517467181056\sqrt2}{230842351450032320669497193036836458276349885044525\pi}$ with `N[...,30]` gives me almost zero ($10^{-74}$), so this function indeed must be simplifiable.

So, how do I convince Mathematica to simplify such hypergeometric function expressions?

Comment: Just an observation, `FullSimplify[(sum2 /. q -> 32) - sum1]` gives `0` without warnings.

Comment: Oh, indeed, using `FullSimplify` instead of `Reduce` gives `True` without warnings. Still, it doesn't reveal $(1)$ without need to put it into expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
expr2 = Sum[(8^(-11 - 2 t) (22 + 4 t)!)/(t! (11 + t)! (11 +2 t)!) 1/(q + t), {t, 0, Infinity}]
% /. q -> 32
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FunctionExpand[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, didn't know of `FunctionExpand`. This is great. Thanks.